# Error when loading CSS with webpack css-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, css-loader

I try to import and reuse a CSS file to be injected in a shadow-root in Typescript but I cannot get it working with the webpack config.
Indeed, I tried adding the following code to Webpack:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options:{
                url: false
        }
    }]
}
```

But when I try to build, I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                 10:49:02 AM

 error  in ./node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.css

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | // Imports
    | ^
  2 | var ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ = require("../../css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
  3 | exports = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(false);



 @ ./node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.css 4:14-207
 @ ./src/extension/content.ts
 @ multi ./src/extension/content.ts
```

I really don't understand what is wrong.

In addition, if I try to import my css file without any loader, doing:

```
const s = require('tippy.js/dist/tippy.css');
```

Then `s` is an empty object.

Does anyone have any idea what could happen here?

Comment: Try using style-loader along with css-loader - [link](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/)